# upper density of set A is 1, upper density of set B is 1, but the upper density of their intersection is not necessarily 1.

Tags: combinatorics

I am now taking a combinatorics class. Our professor give us this question to feed our thinking. But I just cannot see any counterexample. Can any one help?

Comment: Please also put the question in the body of your answer and clearly define what all terms such as "upper density" mean in this context, and I'm sure someone will be along to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $\sigma=\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers with $n_0=1$.

$$A=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}[n_{2k},n_{2k+1})\qquad\text{and}\qquad B=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}[n_{2k+1},n_{2k+2})\;,$$

where the intervals are taken in $\Bbb Z^+$. (Note: for me $0\in\Bbb N$.) Clearly $A\cap B=\varnothing$, so its outer density is $0$. For each $k\in\Bbb N$

$$\frac{|A\cap[1,n_{2k+1})|}{n_{2k+1}-1}\ge\frac{n_{2k+1}-n_{2k}}{n_{2k+1}-1}=1-\frac{n_{2k}-1}{n_{2k+1}-1}\;.\tag{1}$$

If you make $\sigma$ increase fast enough, you can ensure that the ratio in $(1)$ tends to $1$ as $k$ increases, so that the upper density of $A$ is $1$. Moreover, you can arrange for something similar to happen with $B$.

Comment: Thank you! but just one point I want to clarify, what does "outer density" mean?

Comment: @UserQ: You're welcome! It's also called the [upper density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density). It's $$\limsup_n\frac{|A\cap[1,n]|}n\;,$$ which exists even when the asymptotic density doesn't.

Comment: OK! Upper density, then I got it. But here one more thing, because you set up the upper density of A is equal or bigger than 1-(lim tend to zero part) then finally you get upper density of A is bigger than 1 but it cannot be, right? since upper density is [0,1]

Comment: @UserQ: No, it’s always less than $1$: the ratios in $(1)$ are all less than $1$.